# How to authenticate session used for broker-connections in artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am trying to test using [broker-connections](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/amqp-broker-connections.html) to mirror two Artemis servers using docker on my local laptop.

I have setup the two servers in docker-compose using the artemis-adoptopenjdk-11 images from Artemis 2.17.0, one called artemis-1 and the other called artemis-1-m.

I added a few queues to both server's broker.xml like:

```
<addresses xmlns="urn:activemq:core">
  <address name="DLQ">
    <anycast>
       <queue name="DLQ" />
    </anycast>
  </address>
  <address name="ExpiryQueue">
    <anycast>
       <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
    </anycast>
  </address>
  <address name="jms.queue.Sms0Lp"><anycast><queue name="jms.queue.Sms0Lp" /></anycast></address>
</addresses>
```

I added the broker-connection to the primary like:

```
      <broker-connections>
         <amqp-connection uri="tcp://artemis-1-m:5672" name="DRMirror1M" user="artemis" password="artemis">
            <mirror message-acknowledgements="true"/>
         </amqp-connection>
      </broker-connections>
```

And to the mirror like:

```
       <broker-connections>
         <amqp-connection uri="tcp://artemis-1:5672" name="DRMirror1" auto-start="false" user="artemis" password="artemis">
            <mirror message-acknowledgements="true"/>
         </amqp-connection>
      </broker-connections>
```

As a precaution I also set `autoStart=false;` on the port 61616 acceptor on the mirror so that clients couldn't connect to it.

When I look in the management console I see the Mirror queue keeps growing and nothing seems to be going to the other side. When I send messages to a queue they don't show up in the management console on the other side.

In the artemis.log I see the following, which suggests there is some sort of problem with authentication and it's not actually sending the credentials over the wire.

```
2021-03-15 01:32:37,316 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.logger] AMQ111003:
*******************************************************************************************************************************
Success on Server AMQP Connection DRMirror1M on artemis-1-m:5672 after 1 retries
*******************************************************************************************************************************

2021-03-15 01:32:37,379 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222216: Security problem while authenticating: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from artemis-1-m/172.19.0.3:5672. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable
2021-03-15 01:32:37,381 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.handler.ProtonHandler] AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from artemis-1-m/172.19.0.3:5672. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable: ActiveMQSecurityException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from artemis-1-m/172.19.0.3:5672. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.security.impl.SecurityStoreImpl.authenticate(SecurityStoreImpl.java:204) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.createSession(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:1679) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.broker.AMQPSessionCallback.init(AMQPSessionCallback.java:210) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.AMQPSessionContext.initialize(AMQPSessionContext.java:81) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.AMQPConnectionContext.onLocalOpen(AMQPConnectionContext.java:567) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.handler.Events.dispatch(Events.java:47) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.handler.ProtonHandler.dispatch(ProtonHandler.java:564) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.handler.ProtonHandler.flush(ProtonHandler.java:359) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.proton.AMQPConnectionContext.flush(AMQPConnectionContext.java:234) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.protocol.amqp.connect.AMQPBrokerConnection.lambda$doConnect$2(AMQPBrokerConnection.java:259) [artemis-amqp-protocol-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) [netty-all-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) [netty-all-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384) [netty-all-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [netty-all-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-all-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
```

For my test, any simple method of sending credentials over the wire would be appreciated. In production my requirement is that all of the traffic be encrypted over the wire. We don't plan to use any external authentication services (Kerberos, LDAP, etc.) unless strictly required.

Comment: Why are you adding a `mirror` to both brokers? Is the intent not to simply mirror messages from the first broker to the second broker?

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason you prefixed your address and queue with "jms.queue."?

Comment: Wildfly prefixes my queues and addresses with jms.queue, so I used the convention.

Comment: I added the mirror to the second broker for fail-back, as mentioned in the documentation. It is set not to autoStart so it can be enabled and disabled from the management interface.

Comment: What do you mean "for fail-back"?

Comment: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/amqp-broker-connections.html#mirror-example-with-failback

Comment: Please be aware that you can use `anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.` on the `acceptor` for your WildFly clients which use those prefixes. If you configure these properties then you won't have to use the prefixes in your address & queue definitions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229949/discussion-between-thecycoone-and-justin-bertram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was a bug fixed as part of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3150.
It should work after you update to 2.18.0 (not released yet at the time I wrote this answer).

You could perhaps try a snapshot from master or build yourself from master.